# How to reset git pushed first commit into wrong new repo?

Tags: git, github

I made a mistake and added the wrong github remote repository to a project, then pushed... only to realized that I had just pushed to a another *new* repository. How do I flush everything out of that repository and return it back to a "blank" state?

I have tried

```
git update-ref -d HEAD
git push --force origin
```

But nothing and it just says "Everything is up to date".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you did:

```
git update-ref -d HEAD
```

you told git to delete the branch to which `HEAD` pointed (e.g., `master`) in your own local repository.  (I tried it on a test repo, and got this result myself.  I was quite surprised!  I thought it would do nothing, or just possibly delete `HEAD` itself; this behavior seems ... suspect at best.)

You probably want to restore it before doing anything else.  Fortunately, it's now on the remote (`origin`):

```
git fetch origin
git checkout origin/master
```

Now, the problem remaining, at least with regular (non-github) remote repositories, is that you want to delete the accidental branch, but you can't:

```
$ git push origin :master
remote: error: By default, deleting the current branch is denied, because the next
remote: error: 'git clone' won't result in any file checked out, causing confusion.
remote: error: 
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyDeleteCurrent' configuration variable t
remote: error: 'warn' or 'ignore' in the remote repository to allow deleting th
remote: error: current branch, with or without a warning message.
remote: error: 
remote: error: To squelch this message, you can set it to 'refuse'.
remote: error: refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/master
[snip]
```

You could log in to the remote and configure it (or just delete the thing and reinitialize it as an empty repo), if you had access, but you don't, so that's out.

You can probably ask the github people to do this.

Much simpler is this: do nothing.  You want that repository to "act blank", and then you presumably want to push some *other* repository's `master` over there, so just:

```
$ cd .../otherrepo
$ git remote add origin ssh:...
$ git push -f origin master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 229 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://...
 + 187486a...f9bc6a3 master -> master (forced update)
```

That is, this push completely overwrites the previous one.  All the objects (from the wrong repository) that used to be identified by branch `master` in the remote, are now "abandoned" over there, and will be garbage-collected.  The new objects (from the right repository) are now on the remote and pointed-to by branch-name `master` over there.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up overriding the repo with the project that was supposed to go there in the first place and everything got resolved nicely.